# ADD_MASTER_DATABASE procedure changes tns login username

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, tnsnames, multi-master-replication

I'm trying to configure `multi master` with two servers (orclsrc and orcltgt) on `Oracle 11G` (yes, I know it is old but is what we have here) following [this](https://apunhiran.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-setup-multi-masteradvanced.html) guide.

When I'm trying to do:

```
EXEC DBMS_REPCAT.ADD_MASTER_DATABASE (GNAME=> 'REP2', MASTER=>'ORCLTGT',USE_EXISTING_OBJECTS => TRUE,COPY_ROWS=> FALSE, PROPAGATION_MODE=> 'ASYNCHRONOUS');
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04052: error occurred when looking up remote object REPADMIN.SYS@ORCLTGT
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 2
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REPCAT_UTL", line 4280
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REPCAT_MAS", line 2158
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REPCAT", line 146
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

AFAIK I have a proper TNS config because tnsping works ok on both directions.

So the problem seems that when a run former command login action appends or concatenates ".sys" to my username (`repadmin.sys` instead of `repadmin`).

How can I avoid this behaviour?

PS: is there any other better option for `multimaster`?

Comment: The error seems to be about the `@ORCLTGT`part, not the `.sys` part. TNS ping works from your client machine, or from the DB server machines? The TNS alias needs to be in the `tnsnames.ora` that Oracle uses internally from the server - so is it in there? You might need both aliases defined on both servers.

Comment: @AlexPoole my working `tnsping` are in `orclsrc` and `orcltgt` and tnsping each other, so they are in the server machines itself. From your comment maybe is relevant that both tnsping say `Used parameter files: /some/path/sqlnet.ora`, so maybe am I missing `tnsnames.ora` file?

Comment: It wouldn't work without a `tnsnames.ora`. But do you have TNS_ADMIN set in your session, to `/some/path`, which isn't under ORACLE_HOME? The database might not be using the same file you are, I suppose.

Comment: @AlexPoole (i), yes, /some/path is under `ORACLE_HOME`, actually it is `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin`. (ii) TNS_ADMIN is not set on both `src` o `tgt` (maybe that's my issue). (iii) I realized that I do have `tnsnames.ora` file in the same folder than `sqlnet.ora`.